# .htaccess redirect even if directory exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want redirect URL even if directory exist
eg. `example.com/directory` redirect to `example.com/index.html#directory`
This is my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex dispatch.py
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dispatch.py/$1 [L]
```

I tried also:

```
DirectoryIndex dispatch.py
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^zawody$ /dispatch.py/zawody [L]
```

and still dosent redirect...

Answer (score 0):

This line checks if a [directory does not exist](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond).

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

This rule looks for this folder without a following slash or any other content behind it:

```
RewriteRule ^zawody$ dispatch.py/zawody [R,L]
```

If you delete the directory line and try this instead it should work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^zawody/?$ dispatch.py/zawody [R,L]
```

If you want to redirect anything from the zawody directory you would do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^zawody /dispatch.py/zawody [R,L]
```

In the example, you're asking about following the url with the `#` hash or pound symbol.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^zawody /dispatch.py\#zawody [L]
```

Comment: I've updated the code to make the RewriteRule declarations as redirects. Maybe that's what you're after? If they're permanent redirections then you would use `[R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

```
!-d
```

means if the directory doesnt exist

remove that line and you should be ok